# WP Query and WP Mail?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm not familiar with wp code can anyone tell me how to execute an SQL query then trigger a mail ?

My goal is to do a query FIRST to a table once the query is confirmed `SELECT * FROM mytable` I want to trigger a `wp_mail`.

is this correct ?

```
add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html"; ')); 

$email_result = wp_mail('my.email@domain.com', 'Subject', 'Message');

if( $email_result ){//wp_mail() processed the request successfully
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "mytable";

    $ereminders = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT * FROM $table_name
    ") );
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to query a custom table or a Wordpress table? (like wp_posts)

Comment: yes but it's a VIEW table, and i feel like the query should be first because what i understand on the code is once the email is success it will query and not sure how i will do it